# GAC Install in WiX

Tags: wix, installation, gac

I am building an MSI in which I am deploying a dll to GAC using the File element's Assembly=".net" attribute. But this is deploying it to C:\Windows\Assembly instead of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL. Can anyone please help me fix this? I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a 3rd Party DLL and it looks like it was built using an older version of .net and hence it was probably going to the older GAC (C:\Windows\Assembly). Otherwise, just specifying the Assembly=".net" attribute will be enough.